# Android: Disable ListView once clicked?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a list view and when item in the listview clicked, I save the detail to sqlite db using AyscTask which is called from listview's onitemclicklistener. When user randomly clicks many items application crashes as app try to access db in peculier way. This happens when the user is fast enough to click multiple items in the listview before the loading alert shows up.

How can I prevent this?? I tried to disable listview inside the listview's onitemclick method but it didn't work too.

my code

```
//setting up the listview
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        setListAdapter(new TypeArrayAdapter(TypeSelectActivity.this, R.layout.row_type, typeList));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                sectionid = Integer.parseInt(LocationWebService.incidentTypeSectionId
                        .get(arg2));
                incidentid1 = Integer
                .parseInt(LocationWebService.incidentTypeId
                        .get(arg2));

                LocationWebService.IncidentTypeID = incidentid1;
                LocationWebService.sectionID = sectionid;
                new DBTasks().execute(arg2);
                TextView tv=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.label_type);
                TypeString=tv.getText().toString();
                Log.v("TypeSelect", TypeString);

            }
        });
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Use `ProgressDialog` to block the UI for a moment.

Comment: Make a database operation in synchronize. So for one item click, if database operation is going through use progress dialog as per Adil Soomro  says so user can't click on second item.

Comment: the problem is before progress dialog appears user clicks on another list datz where the issue occures :(

Comment: Could you post the code of how you solved it please? I'm having the same problem but I'm not getting anything better with the AsyncTask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using disable the list in AsnykTask -> `PreExecute` and enabling the list in `PostExecute`..