# App crashes when you click several times

Tags: android

In my app the first screen is a list and when you click once it goes ok but if,my mistake or something, you click two or more times before it loads the application crashes. I've been doing a little research but I didn't found anything. I post my code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);
    // Set title
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.mainheader);

    // Get Arguments
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        app = extras.getString("app");
    }

    //Set simulation date   
    TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    date.setText(convertDateToString());
    // set the list adapter: ListView myList =
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    DataBaseAccess ddbb = new DataBaseAccess();
    //Download the data from a database
    lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, myLines,
            flowAlarm, precAlarm));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, ShowGraph.class);
            String[] obj = list.split(";");
            i.putExtra("object name", obj[position]);
            i.putExtra("app name", app);
            i.putExtra("app list", list);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    // Set buttons clickable
    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button calendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendar.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Does anyone knows why?

My LogCat:

```
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.toRealPoint(XYChart.java:699)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at org.achartengine.tools.Pan.apply(Pan.java:64)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at org.achartengine.TouchHandler.handleTouch(TouchHandler.java:106)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onTouchEvent(GraphicalView.java:284)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3952)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1711)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1145)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2217)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1901)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
02-29 13:51:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The ShowGraph activity oncreate:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get arguments
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        object = extras.getString("object name");
        app = extras.getString("app name");
        list = extras.getString("app list");
    }
    // Set title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.headermenu);
    // Download the info from the database

     downloadInfo(app, object);

    // set the button listeners
    listeners();
    //Set checkbox listeners
    setCheckListeners();

    // Drag Meteo
    vg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        RelativeLayout vg1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // int x = (int) event.getX() - offset_x;
                int y = (int) event.getY() - offset_y;
                int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                int h = vg.getHeight() - 40;
                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0;
                if (y > h)
                    y = h;
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                lp.setMargins(0, y, 0, 0);
                selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
                int height = vg1.getHeight();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                lp2.setMargins(0, 0, 0, Math.abs(vg.getHeight() - y));
                // lp2.height = y-height;
                vg1.setLayoutParams(lp2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    RelativeLayout img = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.vg);
    img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                offset_x = (int) event.getX();
                offset_y = (int) event.getY();
                selected_item = v;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I tried with the AsyncTask as I read here but is not working:

[Android: Disable ListView once clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162210/android-disable-listview-once-clicked)

Comment: What is showing in your logcat?

Comment: I've edited the question with the logcat, although I'm not able to pur it into code source form, don't know why!sorry...is a bit messy to see it like that! I edit also the list content in xml layout!

Comment: what is the `Exception` you get? you didn't include that in your logcat post...

Comment: Blindly assumption. If I am not wrong. Just check your variables which are you passed to ShowGraph class in list item click whether its not null when you passed it. put condtion to check it and start activity in this condition. Also at ShowGraph.java class when you get values just check any one of them is not null.

Comment: You put ListLayout twice, instead of ListAdapter. Problem isn't in layout, so put here onStart code of your ShowGraph activity

Comment: I've checked and they are not null, but I found out that it crashes in  ShowGraph activity, before it loads not in Main activity the exception I get is NUllPointerException.

Comment: I've updated with the ShowGraph activity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve it was to add a ProgressDialog in order to prevent people clicking several times when the new activity was loading.

```
MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ShowGraph.this, ""," Loading. Please wait ... ", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In ShowGraph:

```
if (extras != null) {
    object = extras.getString("object name");
    app = extras.getString("app name");
    list = extras.getString("app list");
}
```

If your `extras` is null, then your `app` is null too. So problem can be there

```
 downloadInfo(app, object); //NullPointerException
```

**ALSO**

1) Note that `onCreate()` called once (only for first click). It's better to move your "get Intent" part to `onStart()` method.

2) Use debbuging tools or try to hide your code with comments block by block, to find where is NullPointerException exactly.

```
 /*Like this
 downloadInfo(app, object);
 */
```

Comment: No, it's not that, in downloadInfo I check if they are null or not and  do different things in each case. If I click just once it works perfecctly but if I click twice it crashes! Thanks!

Comment: But what do you mean exactly by: try to hide your code with comments block by block?